# Read Text from large txt file inside zip file

Tags: c#

I am trying to read all text of a TXT file that is inside a ZIP file. The unzipped file has 1GB.
The following code does not throw errors but never ends, is there any way to speed up the process?

```
 var fileText = string.Empty;

 using (var file = File.OpenRead(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zipPath"]))
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        using (var stream = zip.Entries.First().Open())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                try
                {
                    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                   {
                       var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                       fileText = fileText + line;
                    }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean it "never ends". Is it making any progress and it's just taking too long? When you set a breakpoint on the `fileText` assignment, do you see that it's adding new lines on each iteration?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Can you talk us through what you are planning to use `fileText` for?

Comment: When I put a breakpoint I can see that it´s adding lines but it was more than 2 hours and it doesn't has finished reading them yet.

Comment: If I unzip the file first and then read it using the File.ReadAllLines method, it does it almost instantly but this solution wouldn´t be within the possibilities.

Comment: `but this solution wouldn´t be within the possibilities` Why not? You have a solution that works - why struggle with a hard problem if you have an easy solution already working?

Comment: Because I can't unzip the file to the hdd.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var fileText = string.Empty;

 using (var file = File.OpenRead(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zipPath"]))
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        using (var stream = zip.Entries.First().Open())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                try
                {
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                   {
                       var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                       fileText = fileText + line;
                    }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

However, consider using `ReadAllLines` for easiest solution.